# Cloud Firebase analytics not working in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

I want to add firebase analytics in my Xamarin.iOS application.

I have installed the Nuget for analytics **Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Analytics** [Latest Version 6.0.4]

Added argument to Default Configuration of iOS application:

- Argument: -smth
- Extra mlaunch argument: [image: --argument=-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled]

In AppDelegate:

```
Firebase.Analytics.Loader loader1 = new Firebase.Analytics.Loader();
Firebase.InstanceID.Loader loader2 = new Firebase.InstanceID.Loader();
```

When I'm running the app getting this errors:

> 1. MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: *. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native 
>      libraries are properly linked in
> 2. MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: *. The symbol '*' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks 
>      linked with your application.

Comment: I faced the same issue yesterday. My project does not compile anymore. I am also trying to find out a workaround.